# linux + how to delete only the matched number from line

Tags: linux, perl, shell, sed, ksh

How to delete only if number is full matched

I wrote simple sed command ,the  example below by sed ,

my target is to delete the number "1" from the list $NUMBERS

what I need to add to my sed syntax in order to delete only the matched number/s

my example:

```
 [u@h w]# NUMBERS="11 12 13"
 [u@h w]# DEL_NUM="1"
 [u@h w]# NUMBERS="1 11 12 13"
 [u@h w]# echo $NUMBERS | sed s"/$DEL_NUM/ /g"


      2  3
```

while the expected results should be

```
      11 12 13
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
 echo $NUMBERS | perl -pe "s/\b$DEL_NUM\b/ /g"
```

\b matches word boundaries.

Answer (score 1):

There is a way in `sed`: wrap with `<>` the word to be matched:

```
$ echo $NUMBERS | sed "s/\<$DEL_NUM\>/ /g"
  11 12 13
```

This will only replace exact matchings.

`\b` reference on [sidharth answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16272556/1983854) is also valid for sed:

```
$ echo $NUMBERS | sed "s/\b$DEL_NUM\b/ /g"
  11 12 13
```

Answer (score 0):

Using only ksh builtins:

```
function delnum {
    typeset DEL_NUM=$1 i 
    shift || return
    for i; do
        [[ $i == $DEL_NUM ]] || print -n $i ""
    done
}
DEL_NUM="1"
NUMBERS="1 11 12 13"
delnum ${DEL_NUM} ${NUMBERS}
11 12 13
```